# Cannot import javax.validation.constraints in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

I can't import that simple library, i have all jar files, also i tried Ivalidate Caches / Restart. Maybe i have to add validation to build path, but i don't know to which file.
[image]

Comment: Believe IntelliJ: If it can't find the JARs, it means you've put them in the wrong place.  This is easier if you use Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Just found solution, it must be added on Project Structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it.

1. File -> Project Structure
2. In **Modules** click Dependecies, then click green **"+"** on the right side
3. Click **JARs or directiories...** and add JAR files
4. Click **OK**

   THEN:
5. File -> Project Structure
6. In **Artifacts** click **FIX** button on right bottom size
7. Click **OK**

Answer (score 7):

You just need to add the **dependency** **Validation API** in the **pom.xml**:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Links:
https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Comment: And probably restart the IDE

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency in `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What build tool do you use? You obviously forgot to declare your dependencies, that's why IDEA doesn't know where to look for the classes you are trying to import.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Step-by-step:

1. Open "build.gradle" file. It's in your root folder project;
2. Include the line below inside "dependencies{ }":
   implementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
3. Save and close build.gradle file;
4. Next, you will see a short notification on the top of your screen to "Load Gradle Changes". Click on it.

If you don't see any notification, click on Gradle side bar, and then click on "Reload All Gradle Projects".

5. That's all! Your annotation @Valid, @NotBlank ou @NotNull, will work.

Answer (score -1):

If you get this error after attempting to import a Maven project, it may be that you need to check "Import Maven projects automatically" in the Import Project wizard. Without that the IntelliJ build may not be able to locate Maven dependencies, even if they are declared in pom.xml files.